# Solution for "ghost touches" - Procedure to disable a small portion of the screen from being sensitive to touch?

Tags: screen, touchscreen, broken-screen

So I ordered a cheap Chinese phone (umidigi) as a secondary device and the unit I got, out of the box, was afflicted with a faulty display. Troubleshooting it I have diagnosed the problem precisely:

- There is an intermittent false touch input occurring in the bottom right, very far bottom right part only of the screen
- Lowering the brightness appears to minimize the presence of the false input
- Is likely to require disassembly of the device to remedy the issue

I alerted the seller I bought the phone from, and they're sending me a new unit pronto, and told me to just keep this one. Yay.

So, Id like to eventually permanently resolve this phones issue and open it up myself, but in the meantime I'd like to get some use out of it. But, with the ghost touch using the phone with anything other than a Bluetooth mouse is maddening.

The area effected is at the very, very bottom of the phone and may occupy 15px or so at most. I attempted to use a few apps, one called 'Partial Screen' and some others like Screen Shift. However, the adjustments to the display only result in cosmetic changes and do not desensitize the adjusted portion of the screen to touch input and thus the false input creating problems.

Can anyone point me to a procedure, adb input or otherwise, that could ensure that some specified portion of the touch screen will not respect any touch input?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a screen protector that came with it... Take it off !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connect your phone to a PC via ADB and use this command: `adb shell wm overscan left,top,right,bottom` where `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom` are the coordinates upto which your screen works properly.

For example, if my phone with a resolution of 480px × 854px, would have had this problem, I would write `adb shell wm overscan 0,0,0,839` to disable 15px at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's a **hardware issue**. As you are thinking to make that particular portion of the screen less sensitive, it is not possible, because the touch sensor all over the screen is a single unit. The only thing you can do is to **ignore** the touch inputs coming from that affected part of the screen. So, *use an app that can overlay at that portion and can block/ignore the touches at that portion of the screen*. OR, Take your phone for a repair.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Could you suggest any apps that meet your description ? Im doing more research and trial now, as well. Thanks.

Comment: I have found "Partial screen" to be very useful. Although my phone's screen is absolutely OK, but I had tested it. As you had mentioned, it only change the appearance of the screen, it is not like that.